# How to alternate between two images with a timed delay in Java?

Tags: java, android

So I have an app that flips a coin when the user presses a button. Currently it just displays the outcome, but I wanted to add a small loop of heads-tails-heads-tails-heads before displaying the outcome to show that it is being flipped. I was using thread.sleep like this:

```
public void flip(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            coin.setImageResource(R.drawable.heads);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error! :(");
            }
            coin.setImageResource(R.drawable.tails);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error! :(");
            }
        }
    }
```

but instead of displaying the image changes, all that has happened is the app is doing the delays. What have I screwed up?

Comment: Do the same in AsyncTask

Comment: Personally, I'd look to solve this issue using one of the Animation classes in Android, than handling this inside threads.

Comment: As @PPartisan mentioned Animation classes are good for your requirements. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

The delay (in milliseconds) until the Runnable will be executed.

```
   final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        coin.setImageResource(R.drawable.heads);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
        coin.setImageResource(R.drawable.tails);
          }
        }, 500); // milliseconds
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried putting your code inside my for loop, but I'm not getting a delay between image changes. Any suggestions?

Comment: 500 milliseconds is very short. please change delay time. I recommend 5000(5 sec) time off